# I want to change images with respect to a sound in xcode?

Tags: iphone, xcode

I want to change images with respect to a sound in x code?I also want to repeat all this up to repetition number given by user?
Thanks for replay....

Comment: You have to be more specific in your question

Answer (score 0):

Use [AVAudioPlayer](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVAudioPlayerClassReference/Reference/Reference.html) class. This class contains numberOfChannels property. This property you gives number of channels and it synchronize with your images.

Comment: Can you please explain how to do it using AVAudioPlayer numberOfChannels property?